# Multiple arguments in sqllite in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I would like to know how to pass multiple arguments to a raw query in sqllite.

My code is below

```
query() async {

    // get a reference to the database
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

    // raw query
    List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name=?', ['Peter']);

    // print the results
    result.forEach((row) => print(row));

  }
```

In the above code i am passing one argument 'Peter' but what if I want to pass multiple arguments, for example:

```
   List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name=? and last_name=? and year=?', ['Peter'], ['Smith'],[2019]);
```

If I do the code above, I get error "Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 4 found."  can someone show me how to pass multiple arguments to a query in sqllite flutter?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).

You need to put all your arguments into one list and not multiple.
The code below should work like this:

```
List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery(
    'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name=? and last_name=? and year=?', 
    ['Peter', 'Smith', 2019]
);
```

For more examples how to use raw queries see their examples on their [pub.dev page](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#raw-sql-queries).

Comment: thank you very much , I had difficult time to figure out I should use "comma "or "and "to seperate so thank you

Answer (score 12):

Or if you want to use the query function you can do it like this:

```
  String strVal = 'str';
  int intVal = 0;
  String likeVal = 'str';
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('my_table',
      where: "col1 LIKE ? and col2 = ? and col3 = ?",
      whereArgs: ['$likeVal%', strVal, intVal],
      orderBy: 'id',
      limit: 10);
```

Comment: Forgot '%' in like args.