# multiple arguments in sqflite flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I want to search database based on the keyword. if it title or content contains the keyword then return the data. but it send backs nothing.

```
  static Future<List<Note>> searchDocuments(String? keyword) async {
    final database = await DatabaseHelper.database();
 
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> allDocuments = await database.rawQuery(
        'SELECT * FROM docs WHERE title=? and content=?',
        ['$keyword%', '$keyword%']);
```

[checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276690/multiple-arguments-in-sqllite-in-flutter) - doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
await database.rawQuery(
        'SELECT * FROM docs WHERE title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?',
        ['%$keyword%', '%$keyword%']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  await database.rawQuery(
        'SELECT * FROM docs WHERE title="$keyword" AND content="$keyword"');
```

Comment: (1) no such column: b in "SELECT * FROM docs WHERE title=b OR content=b"